# finding synonyms in C#

Tags: c#, ms-office, office-interop

I'm trying to write a code in c# that finds me synonyms of a word.
I'm using the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application` library.
The problem is that the code gives me too many words that are not relevant. It also gives me the opposite words.
anyone have an idea how to improve this code or has another code that's doing it better.
The code I'm using is:

```
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application appWord;      // word application var
        object objNull = null;      // word object method calls require
        // references to objects... create
        // object for null and
        object objFalse = false;      // false entries and language

        object objLanguage = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdLanguageID.wdEnglishUS; // or appropritate lang!

        try
        {
            // Try opening Word app
            appWord = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
        }
        catch (System.Exception exc)
        {
            // could not open word... show error message and return
            MessageBox.Show(exc.Message);
            return;
        }

        // clear synonym listbox lbSynonym
        lbSynonym.Items.Clear();

        // now call get_SynonymInfo to get SynonymInfo structure for
        // word entered in TextBox tbWord
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.SynonymInfo si =
                 appWord.get_SynonymInfo(tbWord.Text, ref (objLanguage));


        // first find out how many meanings were found for word
        int iMeanings = (int)si.MeaningCount;
        if (si.MeaningCount > 0)
        {
            // one or more meanings were found... loop over each
            // (notice SynonymInfo.MeaningList is type System.ArrayList!)
            var strMeanings = si.MeaningList as Array;
            if (strMeanings != null)
                foreach (var strMeaning in strMeanings)
                {
                    // get Synonym List for each meaning... note that
                    // get_SynonymList takes an object ref, thus we
                    // must create objMeaning object
                    var objMeaning = strMeaning;

                    var aSynonyms = si.SynonymList[objMeaning];

                    var strSynonyms = si.SynonymList[objMeaning] as Array;
                    if (strSynonyms != null)
                        foreach (string strSynonym in strSynonyms)
                        {
                            // loop over each synonym in ArrayList
                            // and add to lbSynonym ListBox
                            lbSynonym.Items.Add(strSynonym);
                        }
                }
        }
        else
        {
            // no meanings/synonyms found... set ListBox value to "NONE"
            lbSynonym.Items.Add("NONE");

        }
```

Comment: Opposite words = antonyms.

Comment: Can you provide an input and output.

Answer (score 3):

I've amended your code to a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and this seems to do what you're after... Please let me know if it works for you?

```
void Main()
{
    foreach (var value in GetSynonyms("hot"))
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(value);
    }
}

public IEnumerable<string> GetSynonyms(string term)
{
    var appWord = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
    object objLanguage = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdLanguageID.wdEnglishUS; 
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.SynonymInfo si = appWord.get_SynonymInfo(term, ref (objLanguage));
    foreach (var meaning in (si.MeaningList as Array))
    {
        yield return meaning.ToString();
    }
    appWord.Quit(); //include this to ensure the related process (winword.exe) is correctly closed. 
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(appWord);
    objLanguage = null;
    appWord = null;
}
```

More verbose implementation here: https://gist.github.com/JohnLBevan/c00a02361d4d0a331746995314ad8b58

Example inputs and outputs:

```
dictionary
- lexicon
hot
- warm
- sweltering
- spicy
- passionate
actor
- performer
code
- cypher
- program
- system
- cypher
```

Related documentation for [SynonymInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.synonyminfo_members.aspx).

Comment: No worries; you did most of the work; just made the logical assumption that to get synonyms you'd need to use `SynonymList` rather than that they'd be available as the meanings.  I just got fortunate that whilst testing I realised the results you wanted came earlier in the process.